# mssoapinit fails to initialize WSDL

Tags: soap, servicestack

The MSSOAP client fails initializing the soap12 interface of the Hello Example project.

```
var soap = new ActiveXObject('MSSOAP.SOAPClient30');
soap.mssoapinit('http://<server>/ServiceStack.Hello/soap12');
var retval = soap.Hello('test');
```

The following error is returned:

```
WSDLPort: WSDLPort:The soap:binding subnode on the binding for port WSHttpBinding_ISyncReply is missing HRESULT=0x1: Incorrect function.
 - WSDLService:Processing service SyncReply found no port definitions HRESULT=0x80070057: The parameter is incorrect.
 - WSDLReader:Analyzing the WSDL file failed HRESULT=0x80070057: The parameter is incorrect.
 - Client:One of the parameters supplied is invalid. HRESULT=0x80070057: The parameter is incorrect.
```

I am using ServiceStack version 3.95 with IIS 6.0 and.NET 4.0.30319.

This is the WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="Soap12" 
    targetNamespace="http://schemas.servicestack.net/types" 
    xmlns:svc="http://schemas.servicestack.net/types" 
    xmlns:tns="http://schemas.servicestack.net/types" 

    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
    xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" 
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" 
    xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" 
    xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" 
    xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" 
    xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" 
    xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" 
    xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex">

    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="anyType" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType" />
  <xs:element name="anyURI" nillable="true" type="xs:anyURI" />
  <xs:element name="base64Binary" nillable="true" type="xs:base64Binary" />
  <xs:element name="boolean" nillable="true" type="xs:boolean" />
  <xs:element name="byte" nillable="true" type="xs:byte" />
  <xs:element name="dateTime" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime" />
  <xs:element name="decimal" nillable="true" type="xs:decimal" />
  <xs:element name="double" nillable="true" type="xs:double" />
  <xs:element name="float" nillable="true" type="xs:float" />
  <xs:element name="int" nillable="true" type="xs:int" />
  <xs:element name="long" nillable="true" type="xs:long" />
  <xs:element name="QName" nillable="true" type="xs:QName" />
  <xs:element name="short" nillable="true" type="xs:short" />
  <xs:element name="string" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="unsignedByte" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
  <xs:element name="unsignedInt" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
  <xs:element name="unsignedLong" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedLong" />
  <xs:element name="unsignedShort" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedShort" />
  <xs:element name="char" nillable="true" type="tns:char" />
  <xs:simpleType name="char">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:int" />
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:element name="duration" nillable="true" type="tns:duration" />
  <xs:simpleType name="duration">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:duration">
      <xs:pattern value="\-?P(\d*D)?(T(\d*H)?(\d*M)?(\d*(\.\d*)?S)?)?" />
      <xs:minInclusive value="-P10675199DT2H48M5.4775808S" />
      <xs:maxInclusive value="P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:element name="guid" nillable="true" type="tns:guid" />
  <xs:simpleType name="guid">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="[\da-fA-F]{8}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{12}" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:attribute name="FactoryType" type="xs:QName" />
  <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:ID" />
  <xs:attribute name="Ref" type="xs:IDREF" />
</xs:schema>
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://schemas.servicestack.net/types" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.servicestack.net/types" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="Hello">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Name" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="Hello" nillable="true" type="tns:Hello" />
  <xs:complexType name="HelloResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Result" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="HelloResponse" nillable="true" type="tns:HelloResponse" />
</xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>

    <wsdl:message name="HelloIn">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Hello" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="HelloOut">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:HelloResponse" />
    </wsdl:message>



    <wsdl:portType name="ISyncReply">
    <wsdl:operation name="Hello">
        <wsdl:input message="svc:HelloIn" />
        <wsdl:output message="svc:HelloOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>

    <wsdl:portType name="IOneWay">

    </wsdl:portType>

    <wsdl:binding name="WSHttpBinding_ISyncReply" type="svc:ISyncReply">
        <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name="Hello">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://schemas.servicestack.net/types/Hello" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:binding name="WSHttpBinding_IOneWay" type="svc:IOneWay">
        <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />

    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:service name="SyncReply">
        <wsdl:port name="WSHttpBinding_ISyncReply" binding="svc:WSHttpBinding_ISyncReply">
            <soap:address location="http://<servername>/servicestack/soap12" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>

    <wsdl:service name="AsyncOneWay">
        <wsdl:port name="WSHttpBinding_IOneWay" binding="svc:WSHttpBinding_IOneWay">
            <soap:address location="http://<servername>/servicestack/soap12" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```